# Rundeck URL is not updating the latest hostname after updating rundeck-config.properties and framework.properties

Tags: rundeck

Issue encountered after updating the two properties file, localhost is still the hostname of the server. Note that we had done restarting the server after updating. Also tried commenting the grails.serverURL but still not able to use the updated hostname.

/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties

```
grails.serverURL=http://servername:4440
```

/etc/rundeck/framework.properties

```
framework.server.name = servername
framework.server.hostname = servername
framework.server.port = 4440
framework.server.url = http://servername:4440
```

Linux Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9
Running latest Rundeck version

Comment: Hi, your Rundeck instance is an RPM-based installation or WAR-based installation? Also, which Java JDK version and Rundeck specific version are you using? Regards!

Comment: Try setting server.address parameter to 0.0.0.0 (server.address=0.0.0.0) on your rundeck-config.properties file and relaunch the Rundeck service.

Answer (score 0):

Set `server.address` parameter to `0.0.0.0` (`server.address=0.0.0.0`) on your `rundeck-config.properties` file and relaunch the Rundeck service. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/windows.html#configuring-rundeck) (it's about windows configuration but is the same if you're launching Rundeck from any Linux distribution).